# Update function runtime version of QueueTrigger function application in azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, runtime, queuetrigger

I have queueTrigger azure functions. I am receiving warning about function runtime version update. To update runtime version, I have followed some steps like I update value of "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" key to "~4" and check "Function runtime settings" tab where Runtime version showing as custom(~4)
[image]
[image]

Also I update versions inside setting.json file of function application and update "extensionBundle" version values in host.json file

[image]

[image]

After updating those files, I update function by docker deployment. But it still showing me warning about runtime version update.

[image]

I had updated runtime version of another function app which has **httpTrigger** trigger functions.

[image]

As you can also there is some UI difference also between **Function runtime settings** tabs of both function applications (In 1st Runtime version is with **custom** string and in 2nd it without that string). In this **queueTrigger** function app its not updating runtime version as it still showing warning. Is it something which I doing wrong? How can I update it then? Can someone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

Deployed the Python Versioned 3.6 Azure Function Version 3 basic Http Trigger using VS Code:

This is my  `settings.json`  of the above project:

```json
{
"azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
"azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
"azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
"azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
"azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

[image]

According to  [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#python-version)  of Azure Functions Version & Python Compatibility, Python 3.6 Version is compatible to AFCT (Azure Functions Core Tools) Version 3 only.

**Upgrade Process**:

1. In Azure Portal Function app > Configuration > Function Runtime Settings > Runtime version set 3 to 4.
2. You have to upgrade the Python Version in Local Project along with code changes that are compatible to AFCT Version 4 and Python Versions (>3.7).

[image]

3. This  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli%2Cwindows%2Cin-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-python#upgrade-your-local-project)  of Upgrading Python AF Local Project clearly explains what has to updated before upgrading to the AFCT Version 4.

Note:  *AF - Azure Function, AFCT - Azure Functions Core Tools*

Comment: I have queueTrigger type functions. Secondly as you can see in 2nd screenshot, Runtime version dropdown has only one option "custom(~4)" and do not have any other option. Is it because of queueTrigger type functions?

Comment: I don't think it is because of queue trigger, let me check and update.

Comment: I have updated screenshots of "Function runtime settings" tab of both functions.

Comment: As per my observation, it depends on the runtime stack you choose while creating the function app.  I have created queue trigger function choosing runtime stack as python. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/RqDTaqi.png)

Comment: I had chosen "Docker Container" option for Publish  as I deploy docker image and update image/tag in Registry settings of function app deployment center. May be it has different method to update runtime version for this publish option?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by making change in Dockerfile. Previously I was pulling "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.8" docker image. I have changed this image to "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.8" which fix this issue.